# Conditional Filter in GROUP BY in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

I have the following dataset in which I need to merge multiple rows into one if they have the same key. At the same time, I need to pick among the multiple tuples which gets grouped.

```
1 N1 1 10
1 N1 2 15
2 N1 1 10
3 N1 1 10
3 N1 2 15
4 N2 1 10
5 N3 1 10
5 N3 2 20
```

For example

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (f1:int, f2:chararray, f3:int, f4:int);
G = GROUP A BY (f1, f2);
DUMP G;

((1,N1),{(1,N1,1,10),(1,N1,2,15)})
((2,N1),{(2,N1,1,10)})
((3,N1),{(3,N1,1,10),(3,N1,2,15)})
((4,N2),{(4,N2,1,10)})
((5,N3),{(5,N3,1,10),(5,N3,2,20)})
```

Now, I want to pick if there are multiple tuples in collected bag, I want to filter only those which have f3==2. Here is the final data which I want:

```
((1,N1),{(1,N1,2,15)})   -- f3==2, f3==1 is removed from this set
((2,N1),{(2,N1,1,10)})
((3,N1),{(3,N1,2,15)})   -- f3==2, f3==1 is removed from this bag
((4,N2),{(4,N2,1,10)})
((5,N3),{(5,N3,2,10)})
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: The way I approached was that I took the count of the grouped bag and then filtered the rows which have count > 1 and those which have count ==1. For the set which has count == 1, I was flattening it directly, and for the second set, I used a nested filter. But now, pig is complaining about overloaded function. I am getting this error - ````ERROR 1065: Found more than one load function to use: [PigStorage, org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStorage]````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did with my way as specified in the comment above. Here is how I did it.

```
A = LOAD 'group.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int, f2:chararray, f3:int, f4:int);
G = GROUP A BY (f1, f2);

CNT = FOREACH G GENERATE group, COUNT($1) AS cnt, $1;

SPLIT CNT INTO
    CNT1 IF (cnt > 1),
    CNT2 IF (cnt == 1);


M1 = FOREACH CNT1 {
        row = FILTER $2 BY (f3 == 2);
        GENERATE FLATTEN(row);
     };

M2 = FOREACH CNT2 GENERATE FLATTEN($2);

O = UNION M1, M2;

DUMP O;

(2,N1,1,10)
(4,N2,1,10)
(1,N1,2,15)
(3,N1,2,15)
(5,N3,2,20)
```

Comment: This is excellent. Saved me from lot of pain.